# R loop exiting after first run

Tags: r

Hei,

I have a loop that I want to run to separate a file in multiple tables based on a criteria. Basically I take each unique filename that is found in the psms table and separate those rows into individual files.

```
writeCSVTables <- function(files, psms){

for(i in length(files)){    
name <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(files[i])
write.table(psms[grep(name, psms$file), c("accession", "sequence", "peptide",
                                          "modif", "fixed", "file", "spectrum")],
            paste(name,".corr.csv", sep =""), sep ="\t", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
 }
}
```

My problem is that the loop runs only once for the first file name, then exits as if it where successful. I looked into the files vector and it does contain 2 unique filenames so the loop should run twice. Any suggest ions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead

```
[...]
for(i in seq(length(files))){    
[...]
```

---

### Explanation

The notation `for(i in length(files))` means that the variable `i` will assume all values in the vector next to it, iteratively. `length(files)` is a single value, so it runs exactly once, and exits. Working as designed.

What you probably want is `for(i in seq(length(files)))`. Here, `i` assumes each value in `seq(length(files))` (*i.e.* `1`, `2`, `3`, ..., `length(files)`) iteratively.

---

Other solutions could make better use of vectorization as well.

Answer (score 4):

If `length(files)` is 2 then your for-loop loops over the 1-element vector whose sole element is 2.

In any event -- why use indices at all? Just directly loop over the file names.

Replace

```
for(i in length(files)){    
name <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(files[i])
```

by

```
for(fname in files){    
  name <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(fname)
```